# Programmatically scroll to the top of a NestedScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-nestedscrollview

Is there a way to programmatically scroll to the top of a `NestedScrollView` by also triggering the scroll events for the parent? `smoothScrollTo(x, y)` doesn't delegate the scroll events to the `NestedScrollingParent`.

Comment: Clarify your question more, do you mean to say when the NestedScrollView is inside the coordinator layout?

Comment: to programmatically scroll to any point, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52083678/nestedscrollviews-smoothscrollto-behaves-weird

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I managed to do it (animated scrolling):

```
CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) appBarLayout.getLayoutParams();
AppBarLayout.Behavior behavior = (AppBarLayout.Behavior) params.getBehavior();
if (behavior != null) {
    behavior.onNestedFling(coordinatorLayout, appBarLayout, null, 0, 10000, true);
}
```

where `10000` is the velocity in y-direction.

Comment: if you only like to scroll to hide the appbarlayout like in my case you could do `behavior.onNestedFling(coordinator, appbar, null, 0, -params.height, true);` to reverse it `behavior.onNestedFling(coordinator, appbar, null, 0, params.height, true);`

Comment: Thx. Any idea on how to scroll to the bottom of the nestedscrollview ?

Comment: When the AppBarLayout is expanded, simulating the nested fling will collapse it (which is great), but will not make the NestedScrollView scroll down at the same time...

Comment: Plus, when the AppBarLayout is fully collapsed, using a negative y velocity value will not expand it.

Answer (score 128):

```
NestedScrollView.scrollTo(0, 0);
```

Comment: I am telling your to use `NestedScrollView.scrollTo(0, 0);` to scroll to the top of the `NestedScrollView`. You are welcome.

Comment: This is more generally applied to both ScrollView or NestedScrollView.

Comment: @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        scroll.post(() -> scroll.scrollTo(0, 0));
    }

Comment: Works in C# Xamarin like `MyScroller.ScrollTo(0, 0);`

Answer (score 38):

Another way to smooth scroll `NestedScrollView` to all the way up or down is using `fullScroll(direct)` function

```
nestedScrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
nestedScrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_UP);
```

Comment: fullScroll(View.FOCUS_UP) hidden appbar not coming out. Any Idea

Comment: @Sabbir Dhangot did you layout your `NestedScrollView` below the appbar?

Comment: I have one question I can see that fullScroll receives a view. if I want to scroll to a certain textview, editext, or recyclerView will it scroll to it?

Answer (score 24):

Nothing worked for me, and I don't really know why this worked, but here is my solution and problem.

When adding recycler view to a nested scroll view, it showed recycler view on screen when getting to that activity. In order to scroll all the way up, I had to use this:

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.details_recycler_view);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
ProductDescriptionAdapter adapter = new ProductDescriptionAdapter(this);
adapter.setData(mProduct.getDetails());
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
NestedScrollView scrollView = (NestedScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scroll);
scrollView.getParent().requestChildFocus(scrollView, scrollView);
```

Comment: Wooooow, this is best, damet Garm

Comment: If anyone's problem is that the recyclerview inside the nested scroll view is already scrolled half way when entering the activity, try setting the top most element under root of XML to have the following property android:focusableInTouchMode="true"

Comment: This solution works perfectly where as **scrollView.scrollTo(0,0);**  does not work at all.

Comment: This worked : `scrollView.getParent().requestChildFocus(scrollView, scrollView);`

Answer (score 23):

I also faced similar kind scenario. In my case when I scroll down to end, FAB button should be appears and when user tap on that FAB button should go to the top of the page.
For that I added @SilentKnight answer `NestedScrollView.scrollTo(0, 0);` For go to the top but which is not enough for smooth animation for scroll up.
For smooth animation I have used @Sharj answer which is `NestedScrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_UP);`
But then my AppBar is not visible there fore I have to expanded the AppBar as following `appBarLayout1.setExpanded(true)`. 
So using these three I can able smoothly go to top  of the page.

```
nestedScrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_UP);
nestedScrollView.scrollTo(0,0);
appBarLayout1.setExpanded(true);
```

Comment: appBarLayout1.setExpanded(true); - worked for me! Thanks :)

Comment: Thank you! This is the most correct answer, especially when using appbarlayout

Answer (score 16):

Some time `NestedScrollView.scrollTo(0, 0);` and `scrollview.pageScroll(View.FOCUS_UP);` does not work

At that you need to use  **`fling()`** and **`smoothScrollTo()`** together

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
nestedScrollView.post {
   nestedScrollView.fling(0)
   nestedScrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, 0)
}
```

Answer (score 15):

**You can use this for smooth scroll.**

```
nestedScrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_UP);
nestedScrollView.smoothScrollTo(0,0);
```

**OR for normal scroll**

```
nestedScrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_UP);
nestedScrollView.scrollTo(0,0);
```

Comment: Gr8 job. You save my time

Answer (score 11):

You could easily fake the scrolling on NestedScrollView level. You basically tell the coordinatorLayout that you just scrolled by the height of the toolbar.

```
    NestedScrollView nestedScrollView = (NestedScrollView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.your_nested_scroll_view);

    int toolbarHeight = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar).getHeight();

    nestedScrollView.startNestedScroll(ViewCompat.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL);
    nestedScrollView.dispatchNestedPreScroll(0, toolbarHeight, null, null);
    nestedScrollView.dispatchNestedScroll(0, 0, 0, 0, new int[]{0, -toolbarHeight});
    nestedScrollView.scrollTo(0, nestedScrollView.getBottom());
```

Comment: The only answer that worked for me! I needed to scroll up in coordinator layout (so both nestedScrollView and collapsibleToolbar). I used existing code but toolbarHeight changed to Integer.MIN_VALUE and -toolbarHeight to Integer.MAX_VALUE (as I need opposite dirrection). And then I call  appBarLayout.setExpanded(true, true);
Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

I tried all the above responses, nothin seemed to work but I only needed a postDelayed.

```
    scrollview.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            listener.setAppBarExpanded(false, true); //appbar.setExpanded(expanded, animated);
            scrollview.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
        }
    }, 400);
```

Answer (score 4):

Add the line two times .worked for me

```
nestedScrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_UP);
nestedScrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_UP);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the View.scollTo(int x, int y) instead to scroll to the top.

```
findViewById({your NestedScrollView resource id}).scrollTo(0, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had problem with NestedScrollView when I used than with RecyclerView .
This code worked for me:
***nestedScrollView!!.getParent().requestChildFocus(nestedScrollView, nestedScrollView);***

```
    val recyclerViewSearch = activity?.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recycler)
    recyclerViewSearch.setAdapter(setAdapterSearch())

    val nestedScrollView = activity?.findViewById<NestedScrollView>(R.id.bottom_sheet_Search)
    nestedScrollView!!.getParent().requestChildFocus(nestedScrollView, nestedScrollView);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I scroll to an item of RecyclerView when RecyclerView is inside NestedScrollView

First, get an `item height` then scroll to the `position` that you want.

```
val itemHeight =
    binding.calendarRecyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(0)!!.itemView.height
binding.nestedScrollView2.smoothScrollTo(0, position * itemHeight)
```

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin:

```
scrollView.parent.requestChildFocus(scrollView, scrollView)
```