# Half expanded Collapsing toolbar

Tags: java, android

How can I create a half-expanded toolbar? Something like that WhatsApp profile page.

I've tried `scrollBy` and `scrollTo`, but they don't seem to work.

Even `dispatchNestedScroll`, `onNesterScroll` and `onNestedPreScroll` don't seem to work.

Comment: can you please make it more clear ?

Comment: Did you find a solution until now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem by adapting this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34920495/5369519 and using the following code:

```
nestedScrollView.post(() -> {
        int appBarHeight = appBar.getHeight()/2;
        nestedScrollView.startNestedScroll(ViewCompat.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL);
        nestedScrollView.dispatchNestedPreScroll(0, appBarHeight, null, null);
        nestedScrollView.dispatchNestedScroll(0, 0, 0, 0, new int[]{0, -appBarHeight});
    });
```

This simulates scrolling halfway down.
Just using `NestedScrollView.scrollTo()` is not enough to trigger the scroll events for the parent.

Comment: I already found an answer long ago. But this answer sums up what I did. I made the nestedScrollView scroll 50$ the height of the appbar, making the appbar half collapsed

Comment: Did you also encounter problems with a flickering UI? I added a question for this problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61938816/5369519

Comment: No not at all, it was a fine implementation.

Answer (score 0):

To create the collapsing toolbar, [CollapsingToolbarLayout](https://material.io/develop/android/components/collapsing-toolbar-layout/) integrates with AppBarLayout, CoordinatorLayout, Toolbar, and a scrollable content view, such as RecyclerView

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that, my question is scrolling the toolbar to mid way of it's collapsing state